# Excel Formula needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know someone has asked a very similar question, but I need to take it a bit further than what their request was so here it is...

I'm in need of an equation to compare two columns and have a third column display whether there was matching results or not. So something to look whether my inputs in column B are in column A and if this is the case then returning a 1 in a third column or 0 if otherwise. I do have my "column A" in a different sheet fyi. Please enlighten me!

```
Name1,Name2,Match
John,Ricardo,1
David,Martha,0
Leslie,Melanie,0
Marie,John,1
Ricardo,Mathew,0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate on StackOverflow: [Excel how to find values in 1 column exist in the range of values in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489148/excel-how-to-find-values-in-1-column-exist-in-the-range-of-values-in-another)

Answer (score 2):

In column C, start in C1 if your Data start in Row1 write the following:

**=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),1,0)**

B1 is the name in the second column, $A$1:$A$5 is the initial column that you want to compare column B to it, isnumber to prevent from error in case of no match, match return the row number of the matching cell and error if not.
If Column A is in another sheet fyi use:

**=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,fyi!$A:$A,0)),1,0)**

and you can drag the formula down

Answer (score 0):

`=COUNTIF($A:$A,B2)>0`

Credit goes to [tigeravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665425/tigeravatar) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489148/excel-how-to-find-values-in-1-column-exist-in-the-range-of-values-in-another):

[image: Credit goes to @tigeravatar]